# Do the trace and determinant of an operator remain the sum/product of its eigenvalues if the underlying field is finite?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

For fields of characteristic $0$ one can derive from the Jordan normal form that the trace/determinant of an operator are equal to the sum/product of its eigenvalues. Does this fact remain true when the characteristic is $p>0$? I feel like this statement should be derivable from the definition of the characteristic polynomial, but I'm unsure whether the positive characteristic can muck things up.

Comment: Yes, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107789/does-it-always-hold-that-the-product-of-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-is-its-det).

Comment: Yes, these properties still hold regardless of the characteristic of the field. Keep in mind that eigenvalues might not be elements of the field, but of extensions to the (finite) field, or of the field's algebraic closure if you prefer.

Comment: Jordan normal form also works for fields of arbitrary characteristic.